# output HTML text before variable

Tags: jquery, html

I am simply trying to add, an additional nested `span` with my Zip Code Text. But, I may also change this to a radio button down the line.. The below is not working, `innerob["Zipcode"]` prints my values still, but it never adds the HTML before it, I also tried `append` and `prepend`.

```
myjson[ZipSearch].forEach(function(innerobj,index){

    $('span.zip'+index).html('<span>Zip Code</span>' + innerobj["Zipcode"]);
    ..................
```

Comment: Heya Captain Ron -- apparently it's taboo to provide a code snippet and ask for more code (got a couple of negative dings for it).  Who knew.  Anyways, the code you provided seems to work in a code snippet.  Could you provide more of the code at work?

Comment: Thanks @Doug I am doing this with a forEach maybe that is why; I have added that- I noticed in your sample, you didn't include index accounting for the for, maybe that's why..

Comment: I was wondering about the index and where that was being generated ... what does your HTML look like? Is it possible to drop some of it into a code snippet or a codepen to show the code in action?

Comment: So, my best guess -- after trying to reverse engineer what you have is that when you're calling `myjson[ZipSearch]` it should be `myjson["ZipSearch"]` The first is looking for a key that matches the string assigned to a variable of `ZipSearch` where the second is explicitly looking for the key "ZipSearch".

Comment: https://codepen.io/doughensel/pen/jRomby -- it still looks as though your code in general is correct. I made some assumptions in my reverse engineering so if things don't match, then there's probably a problem with what I'm assuming vs. the reality